# Kudu (Git on IIS) cannot create application

Tags: git, iis, kudu

I download Kudu project for deploy on IIS via Git and I have follow this post https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Getting-started

But when I try the option create application it never ends processing the request.

I debug the project on Visual Studio and find that it fails in the next sentence:

```
Namespace Kudu.SiteManagement
Class SiteManager
Method CreateSiteAsync

// Wait for the site to start
await OperationManager.AttemptAsync(() => WaitForSiteAsync(serviceUrls[0]));
```

and its sends to catch block with execute the next that is the part that never ends.

```
catch
{
  try
  {
      DeleteSiteAsync(applicationName).Wait();
  }
  catch
  {
      // Don't let it throw if we're unable to delete a failed creation.
  }
  throw;
}
```

I try giving read/write permissions to the apps folder without success.